# Can PLSQL retrieve file from external shared folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use PLSQL scheduler job to retrieve .csv file on periodic basis.

```
F := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('abc.com\folder\', 'ItemStatusCSV.CSV', 'R');
    IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(F) THEN
```

But it gives out this error:

```
ORA-29280: invalid directory path
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478
```

Comment: post that as an answer so we can upvote it @mathguy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access a directory from within Oracle (including PL/SQL), you need to "create a directory" using the `create directory` command. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm

This does NOT create a new filesystem directory, it only makes it visible to Oracle. The directory must exist in the FS and have the necessary permissions set up in the host OS. Then the owner of your application must be granted rights on the Oracle directory object.

Has any of that been done in your case?

Comment: Actually I don't get what you are trying to say.The path is on another server. Basically the server which the DB resides on has permission on that server.

Comment: When all else fails, read the documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS70919 the first parameter is `location` which *"is a **directory object name** and must be specified in upper case. Read privileges must be granted on this directory object for the UTL_FILE user to run FOPEN."*